# SVG opacity animation on hover with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I have SVG which contain two rings: inner and outer. I'm trying to create an animation, where svg on hovered shows inner ring instantly, and outer after 300ms.

I've tried with `keyframes` animation, but apparently I cannot trigger child element animation when parent is hovered. See [this pen](https://codepen.io/selenir/pen/KvbEEG).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you were triggering the keyframe animation on the `<svg>` element itself, then telling one of the elements inside it to have a delayed animation.

You can only add properties like `animation-delay` on the elements being animated, so I moved the animation to the `<circle>` elements. Here you go:

```css
svg {
  width: 202px;
  height: 202px;
}

svg:hover circle {
  animation: show-inner 1s;
}

svg circle.ring-outer {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}

@keyframes show-inner {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 202 202" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="101" cy="101" r="100" stroke="#7b82c7" stroke-width="1" fill="none" class="ring-outer"/>  
  <circle cx="101" cy="101" r="76" stroke="#7b82c7" stroke-width="1" fill="none" class="ring-inner"/>  
</svg>
```

Comment: I totally forgot that I can access children elements during state like `svg:hover circle`. One more question: can I remove transition effect in order to make circles appear instantly?

Comment: @Selenir Not sure I understand your follow-up question. Your animation is set to be 1 second long - are you just trying to make it so there's no fade animation?

Comment: Yes, I figured out it's possible by using `0% { opacity: 1 }` keyframe. Thanks for help!